# Converting DTO to Entity Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

My current situation is that I have an `abstract` model, in which many other models inherit from. The API consumes a "DTO" object, that is essentially one big object that contains all of the possible fields for each subclass, due to the client calling the service. I've created a solution for this, but it feels like it has some bad "smells". Here is an example of the setup:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public Long id;
    public Long name;
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    public Date startDate;
}

public class Student extends Person {
    public Double gpa;
}

public class PersonDTO {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public Date startDate;
    public Double gpa;
    public String type;
}
```

I want to convert the DTO to its concrete subclass with initialization. I've solved that by creating a factory and overriding a method in each of the subclasses:

```
public class PersonFactory {

    public Person getInstance(String type) {
        if (type.equals("Student")) {
            return new Student();
        } else if (type.equals("Employee")) {
            return new Employee();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {

    public Double gpa;

    /**
     * Initializes the additional fields in the subclass
     * from the PersonDTO.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(PersonDTO dto) {
        this.gpa = dto.gpa;
    }
}
```

So the calling class will do the following:

```
public Person createPerson(PersonDTO dto) {
    Person person = new PersonFactory().getInstance(dto.type);
    person.name = dto.name;
    person.id = dto.id;
    person.initialize(dto);
}
```

To put this into perspective a little more, the model superclass (in this example, `Person`) has about 15 fields, and the subclasses can have up to 5 or 6, making using a constructor cumbersome. I feel like having the `initialize` method is a bad practice, and couples the Person class to the DTO class (this also violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

Ideally, I'd like to create a `Mapper` or `Translator` class, that will translate the DTO into the concrete subclass, but I keep running into the following issue with initializing the common fields:

```
public class PersonMapper implements Mapper<PersonDTO, Person> {

    public Person map(PersonDTO dto) {
        if (dto.type.equals("Student")) {
            Student person = new Student();
            setupCommonFields(person, dto);   // required to call this method
            person.gpa = dto.gpa;             // inside of every block
            return person;
        } else if (dto.type.equals("Employee")) {
            Employee person = new Employee();
            setupCommonFields(person, dto);
            person.startDate = dto.startDate;
            return person;
        }
    }

    private void setupCommonFields(Person person, PersonDTO dto) {
        person.id = dto.id;
        person.name = dto.name;
    }
}
```

This seems like a clearly simple problem to solve, but I can't seem to come up with the most perfect solution. Is there a better-designed solution for this?

Comment: 1) In your `PersonFactory`, you `return new Person()` for an unknown type. And `Person` is an abstract class. That's not going to compile
2) You can call your `setupCommonFields(person, dto);` method just before returning person in the PersonMapper#map method. You do not need to call it in every block. You'll have to get rid of returns in every block in that case, which is ok.

Comment: @NikhilPatil I can't call `setupCommonFields` at the end, because `person` would be out of scope. If I moved the `person` declaration to the top of the method, I'd have to declare it as a `Person`, keeping me from setting the fields on the subclasses, i.e. `person.startDate = dto.startDate`.

Comment: @NikhilPatil I realized I had an extra `return person` at the end of that `map` method that wasn't valid, which may have prompted your suggestion.

Comment: Casey, take a look at this http://pastebin.com/esbTzDAP Improvised over you mapper implementation. Although, I have to say that I did not understand from where you got the `person` in `person.type.equals("Student")` I don't see any such variable in scope.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PersonMapper implements Mapper<PersonDTO, Person> {

    public Person map(PersonDTO dto) {
        Person person = createPerson(dto);
        setupCommonFields(person, dto);
        return person;
    }

    private Person createPerson(PersonDTO dto) {
        if (person.type.equals("Student")) {
            Student person = new Student();
            person.gpa = dto.gpa;
            return person;
        } else if (person.type.equals("Employee")) {
            Employee person = new Employee();
            person.startDate = dto.startDate;
            return person;
        }
    }

    private void setupCommonFields(Person person, PersonDTO dto) {
        person.id = dto.id;
        person.name = dto.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Dragan, I noticed you helped for few people with mapping. Could you take a look at this? I have no idea how to solve that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110291/custom-dto-interface-to-entity-mapper